# Is there a way to see the logs behind the execute query?

Tags: java, logging, driver

I'm working on a project that uses i-net Opta2000 driver for database connection in a java application. I'm stuck at a point where a complex query takes around 2 minutes time to execute but the same query when executed from query browser takes time from 2-5 seconds. Also, when I hard coded this query in the application and executed it, it again took just few seconds time.

I then searched online for Driver logging and found the following statement that I used in my applycation - **DriverManager.setLogStream(System.out);**

And I have written logs before and after the execute query to check the timestamp too. However, after this logging (driver logging mentioned above) I found that after the control reaches the execute query, it displays - "connection.close". Sometimes, it is just printed once, sometimes twice or thrice and sometimes I don't see it at all.  This "connection.close" is beyond my understanding. If anyone can explain me why I see this and also if there is any other way to see the logging behind the execute query statement.

I searched and tried setting DB logs in log4j but this couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: Are you using DB connection pool ? If yes which one ? Do you have validate on connection borrow active ?

Comment: No, I'm not using DB connection pool. What is connection borrow active?